# Emit a value from an input component Vue 3 gives a warning

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to Emit a value from an input component Vue 3, then have Input.vue components like this:

```
<!-- eslint-disable vue/no-mutating-props -->
<template>
    <div class="mb-6">
        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-grey-darker text-xs font-bold mb-2" :for="id">
            {{ label }} <span class="text-red-600" v-if="isRequired">*</span>
        </label>
        <input :id="id" v-model="modelValue" @input="emit('update:modelValue', modelValue)" :class="inputClasses" :type="type"
            :placeholder="placeholder">
        <ValidationMessage v-if="validation" :validation="validation" :field="id" />
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import ValidationMessage from '@/components/ValidationMessage'

defineProps({
    isRequired: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    },
    label: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    modelValue: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    type: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    placeholder: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
    },
    validation: {
        type: Object,
        default: null,
    },
    inputClasses: {
        type: String,
        default: "appearance-none block w-full bg-grey-lighter text-grey-darker border border-red rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3",
    },
})

const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
</script>
```

and i use that Input.vue to my Create.vue:

```
<Input isRequired label="Judul" id="title" v-model="course.fields.title" type="text" placeholder="Masukkan judul" :validation="validation" />
```

But why there is an warning on console log say:

```
Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "modelValue". Expected String with value "undefined", got Undefined
```

I have no idea where is my mistake for emit a value.

Update:
`course.fields.title` its come from my pinia course.js, and i use my course store to Create.vue. Here its my pinia state:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { useToast } from 'vue-toastification'
import axios from 'axios'
import { handleError } from '@/utilities/handleError'

const toast = useToast()

function getInitialFields() {
  return {
    organizer: '',
    courseCategory: '',
    title: '',
    description: '',
    thumbnail: null,
    statusPaid: '',
    price: 0,
    dateStart: '',
    dateEnd: '',
    deadlineRegister: '',
    locationTraining: '',
    haveCertificate: '',
    linkGroup: '',
    show: ''
  }
}

export const useCourseStore = defineStore('course', {
  state: () => ({
    fields: getInitialFields,
    filter: {
      title: '',
    },
    loading: false,
    data: [],
    pagination: {
      currentPage: 0,
      totalPages: 10,
      totalItems: 0,
    }
  }),
```

Comment: Can you show us what `course` looks like ? The error seems to come from here

Comment: The warning means what it says. course.fields.title  value is undefined. `'update:modelValue', modelValue)` - this is a mistake, it doesn't make sense to emit model value to itself. Possibly should be `@input="emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"`

Comment: @nook its come from my course pinia state.

```fields: { title: '' }```

Comment: i have try to update like that, but there is still a warning @EstusFlask

Comment: I have update my question, add my pinia store @nook

Comment: So that means that somewhere you have `const course = useCourseStore()`, right ?
I think @EstusFlask 's comment is right about emitting the new value instead of the model itself. Also, don't bind the prop as a model, use `:value="modelValue" @input="emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"` instead

Comment: thanks, i have try change:
```<input :id="id" :value="modelValue" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)" :class="inputClasses" :type="type" :placeholder="placeholder">``` and in Create.vue: ```<Input isRequired label="Judul" id="title" v-model="course.fields.title" type="text" placeholder="Masukkan judul" :validation="validation" />```

Comment: but the warning is still here @nook

Comment: or i should one by one write const title = ref('') for v-model? I mean, i cant use my fields from pinia state? @nook

Comment: @ASHafizullah You can with pinia storeToRefs, but it may be not a good idea. It's a doubtful practice to update a store without actions because these changes cannot be easily tracked. It maybe undesirable to update a state before submit

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks, so its better to use reactivity in create.vue first, before sent that reactivity data to pinia store?

Comment: @ASHafizullah Hard to say because you didn't post it. But if you need to have a separate form state that is copied to the store only on submit and not instantly then that's it.

Comment: @EstusFlask yea, because i think its double times add a lot of fields first in create.vue with reactivity, then i have a plan to separate the Input components, if i not separate the components, its no problem to use ```course.fields.title``` for v-model. I see an example tutorial, they create ```const title = ref('')```, but i think its no too simple.